# When I upload my wordpress app from localhost to the live site the font and images get smaller

Tags: html, fonts, size

This has me stumped.  When I upload my WordPress application to my networksolutions hosted server everything on the pages gets a little bit smaller.  Images, fonts, table divs etc all compress a little bit.  The page displays ok, everything is just smaller then it is when I view them on my localhost laptop.  And it's not just wordpress.  It happens with everything I opload to my host server.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: At some point, you accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl + -</kbd> on the remote site, causing the browser to remember the change in zoom level for the entire domain. I think Firefox does that by default.

Try resetting the zoom level in your browser.

Comment: Yes I think you're onto something.  I checked using IE, Oprah and Safari and it doesn't happen.  It only happens with Chrome. I wish I had opened the site from another browser before I spent all day trying to fix my css and do tricks with .htaccess lol.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bill you're welcome. I think Ctrl+0 should trigger a zoom level reset in Chrome - try it out